# There's another way to add an event render?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Apparently the event `renderEvent` creates problems on the agenda day, in fact when I drag an event from the column 0 to the same column, I get that the event has been moved to the first column, and this is wrong. You can see an example here:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jc07k3dd/56/)

**incriminated code:**

```
unavailablePeriod =
{
     'title': "unav",
     'start': start,
     'end': date_end,
     'allDay': false,
     'color': '#BEBEBE',
     'editable': false,
     'className': 'fc-unavailable',
     'column': 0
};
```

I would like to know if there is an alternative method that allows me to get around this situation.

Comment: Isn't that because it automatically detects the collision?

Comment: Uhm, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: The unavailable 'appointment' is preventing you from dropping anything on column-0. It gets bumped to column-1. If that's not your problem then you'll need to give a better description.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly my problem. I think this is due to render that event creates the bug do not know exactly.

Comment: I don't think this is a bug, it's a feature. Do you want to allow overlapping appointments?

Comment: If I move an event from the column 0 to 1 and the event is moved to the next there is a problem nope? So it's a bug. Anyway I want to allow the drop.

Comment: I can't drop an event on column 0, so how do you move one from 0 to 1?

Comment: Me is just an example. If I move an event from 0 to the same column ( 0 ) I get 1, this is a problem for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94615/discussion-between-dillinger-and-halcyon).